# How to hide soft keyboard on android 11?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-11

I have an app using to scan barcode, so I want to hide the soft keyboard.
My app worked fine on devices with android 7, 9... but when I installed it on device run android 11, the keyboard display when I scan.

I searched and tried many ways, like this in Manifest:

> android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

Or this in activity:

> InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
> imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

None of these works. Does anyone have different solutions, please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is two different methods for activity and fragment, Hope it might work for you.

```
// Method : Hide Keyboard
    @JvmStatic
    fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
        val imm = activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        var view = activity.currentFocus
        if (view == null) {
            view = View(activity)
        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun hideKeyboardInFragment(context: Context?, view: View?/*Your EditText*/) {
        if (context != null && view != null) {
            val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is worked for me, please check

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Context context) {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    // check if no view has focus:
    View v = ((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus();
    if (v == null)
        return;
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code . send `getActivity()` every where...

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    if (activity != null) {
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();

        if (view == null) {
            view = new View(activity);
        }

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        if (imm != null) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```